# Switch onImage offImage attribute for iOS 8?

Tags: ios

How can I put the off/on image for Switch control?

I already tried assigning values to

```
ourSwitch.onImage = ourImage
ourSwitch.offImage = ourImage
```

trough the storyboard designer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/onImage

Comment: Seems to be deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843747/why-uiswitch-onimage-offimage-properties-are-not-working-on-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
ourSwitch.onImage = ourImage
ourSwitch.offImage = ourImage
```

?